# find results from table after update, where (attribute integer) is equal to the (primary id integer)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating an object in a table with attributes : :primary_id, :zucode_number, :zucode_email

The updated row object does NOT have the attributes :zucode_number and :zucode_email . 
Other different rows in the same table do have the attributes i need, :zucode_number and :zucode_email.

:zucode_number(integer) can be equal to, is sometimes equal to the :primary_key(integer)

How to get the rows where :zucode_number is equal to :primary_key and send email to :zucode_email on those rows.

Hope this makes sense... 
Ive been, and i am, struggling with this, and can't get it to work. Thanks in advance for your help. 
Asked another question similar yesterday but think it wasn't clearly explained.

I am updating (successfully) the object(zucode), sending it through a link to:

```
def changezu
zucode = Zucode.where( id: params[:id], secret2: params[:secret2] ).first
if zucode
  respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to edit_zucode_path, notice: 'Make changes!.' } #edit_zucode_path
  format.json { head :no_content }
```

end
  end
 end

my update method is :

```
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @zucode.update(zucode_params) 
    format.html { redirect_to @zucode, notice: 'Zu was successfully updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @zucode }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @zucode.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end   
 end
end
```

UPDATE:: 
added to controller :.

```
 after_action :trynew, only: [:update]
```

and

```
def trynew

@zucode = Zucode.where("zucode_number=id")
     #ZuMailer.mymail.(zucode).deliver
end
```

with the mailer commented out, it does not give error but nothing happens. Looking into log the correct rows are not being selected or mentioned. I only see reference to the updated row. If i run with the mailer i get error for "wrong arguments 0 of 1"

Comment: Hey @Francisco, did you try adding a callback "after_update", and running a query in that similar to "Zucode.where('zucode_number=id').
This should work for you

Comment: Hi @jaspreet21anand thanks for your help. Ive just tried and gives me routing error =undefined method `after_update' for ZucodesController:Class , creating a route as for other actions, doesn't seem to work. not sure how to go from here..

Comment: 'after_update' is a callback..
it will be de used in model "Zucodes"
see the exact syntax in guides, it is like "after_update :method_to_call"
your class must be inherited from ActiveRecord::Base..
In case you are unable to follow, please study http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see, that you need to use callbacks of object lifecycyle.

I am assuming that you have a model called `Zucode` .

Inside that model add `after_update` method.

```html
class Zucode

  after_update :method_to_call

  def method_to_call
    zucodes = Zucode.where('zucode_number=id')
    #perform action on zucodes
  end

end
```

The method `method_to_call` will get called each time a Zucode is updated.